# Jquery getting li element id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a UL list which has 4 LI elements like this

```
<ul class="pagination " id="loadMore">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link prevR" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link active" id="1" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="2" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="3" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="4" href="#">4</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link nextR" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
```

and i am trying to get id of the li element as

```
$('#loadMore').on('click', function () {
   var page = $('#page');
   var msg = $('#loadMoreMsg');
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
   return false;
});
```

But it shows undefined in alert, 
i have tried many solutions but nothing worked, any ideas ?

Comment: Working fine at our end. and also you have unexpected : at last

Comment: I'm not that jquery genius but should'nt your query be more like `$('#loadMore li')`?

Comment: dis you added jquery library ? because it's working fine

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes i have ]

Comment: @user7597883  did these elements are generated dynamically?

Comment: Your wrote: _"and i am trying to get id of the li element as"_; Your li's don't have a id. oO

Comment: @user7597883  your `li` don't have any id

Comment: @AlivetoDie i am givng id like  id="2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `li` don't have `id` attribute at all .It's the links inside `li` which have id's.

To get them do like below:-

```js
$('#loadMore li').on('click', function () {
  alert($(this).find('a').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination " id="loadMore">
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link prevR" href="#" id="prev">Prev<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link active" id="1" href="#">1</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="2" href="#">2</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="3" href="#">3</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="4" href="#">4</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link nextR" href="#" id="next">Next<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code

```
$('ul.pagination li').on('click', function () {
  var page = $('#page');
  var msg = $('#loadMoreMsg');
  alert($(this).find('a').attr('id'));
  return false;
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fqyhkd30/1/

Comment: Adding listener to `$('ul.pagination')` will suffice and recommended, reference - https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/. Check a working solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406671/jquery-getting-li-element-id/43406791#43406791

Answer (score 3):

If it is not working at all, then I'm assuming that  you are appending the list dynamically. If that is the case, then use the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#loadMore', function () {
     var page = $('#page');
     var msg = $('#loadMoreMsg');
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: I have do so but it is showing the id of Ul element not li

Answer (score 2):

> and i am trying to get id of the li element as

Your li elements doesn't have `id` attr. I guess you want to get `a` `id` attr.

Here is how you do it, using jQuery `.delegate` and `.on`. We bind an event to `ul#loadMore`.

```js
// .delegate
$('#loadMore').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
  
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var classL = $(this).attr('class');
  
  console.log(id, classL);
});


// .on 
//$('#loadMore').on('click', 'a', function() {
//  
//  var id = $(this).attr('id');
//  var classL = $(this).attr('class');
//  
//  console.log(id, classL);
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="pagination " id="loadMore">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link prevR" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link active" id="1" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="2" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="3" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="4" href="#">4</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link nextR" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.target` to get clicked element.

```
$('#loadMore').on('click', function (e) {
  var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
   console.log(id);
 });
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dspoonia7/jfdmo9hu/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `id` attribute of all the `li` element like brlow :-

```
<li class="page-item" id="value"></li>
```